# Change DNS on Android - via Settings/Network&Internet/Advanced/Private DNS ... or via Settings/Wi-Fi/Modify network/Advanced options/IP Settings?

Tags: wi-fi, mobile-network, dns, private-dns

Device is on Android 9. NOT rooted.

I want to set the DNS to CIRA (or Cloudfare or whatever, not the point). Yes my wifi router is already set to proper DNS. If I am not at home I want the device to have set DNS.

Question 1:

Is how do I do I set DNS on Android for Wifi but also for Mobile connection?

I looked at a couple of sites recommend to modify the Wifi setting as the easiest method. I don't want to install 3rd party VPN loopback tool because I use extenral VPN so I don't know how that will work together.

This talks about 8 methods to set the DNS. Only handful would apply to me:

https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/guide-how-to-change-dns-in-android-device-8-methods.3273769/

However, this page talks about setting up yet another way.

https://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-turn-on-private-dns-mode-on-android-and-why-you-should/

So I am a bit confused. It looks like the 2nd link is not setting the specific Wifi. Is it going to apply to LTE mobile connection? My device offers both ways to set up:

via *Settings/Network&Internet/Advanced/Private DNS* ...

or

via *Settings/Wi-Fi/Modify network/Advanced options/IP Settings*

So is this the best way to setup via the Private DNS?

Question 2:

What do I enter in the box "Private DNS", is both word domain and the IP address okay?

Question 3:

If I root my device, do the rooted methods work better?

Answer (score 0):

Anyways disregard the questions. I found the answer. The new setting was introduced in Android 9.

https://www.xda-developers.com/block-ads-on-android/
[https://www.xda-developers.com/block-ads-on-android/][1]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).